# App folder in Dropbox

Tags: ios, dropbox

In my application I want to fetch all audio files from Apps/App Folder using Dropbox api. I have used sync api and Datastore api but I am not able to create App folder inside 'Apps/'.
Please any one help me to find where I am wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you created a Dropbox app on their developer site ? This should auto create the root dir for you I think.

Comment: Yes, I have created Dropbox app on https://www.dropbox.com/developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you authenticate the app within iOS it should create the folder for you, it's root dir would be '/'. As seen on their docs:

http://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ios

Near the bottom? This will show you how to list all files.

EDIT:

From the link you gave me:

> "With a file system in hand, you can start reading and writing files
>   (represented by a DBFile). If you're using the App folder permission,
>   your App Folder won't contain any files when a user first links with
>   your app, but it's easy to create one."

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/devguide#app-permissions

> "App folder
>
> A dedicated folder named after your app is created within the Apps folder of a user's Dropbox. Your app gets read and write access to
>   this folder only and users can provide content to your app by moving
>   files into this folder. Your app can also read and write datastores
>   using the Datastore API."

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I already mentioned that I want to fetch all audio files. The link you have given me will search file in all folder. But I want to sync with only one folder i.e. Apps/App folder.

Comment: When you list all the files do you see the Apps folder ? You can navigate through to there ?

Comment: that is the problem, its not creating App Folder inside 'Apps/'. I am following this https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/ios

Comment: Ah ok. Forgive me it's been a few years since I looked at dropbox. Let me have a look. I have done this before!

Comment: Which permissions have you given the app ?

Comment: Ahh I think you need to set App Folder ? Check my edit:

Comment: there is two option for permission 1)Files and datastores 2)
Datastores only, I have tried both option but still facing same issue.

Comment: Check the link to permissions in my edit. There are ~5 permissions.

Comment: Thank you so much. Finally I got the solution to my issue.

Comment: Was it the App Folder permission ? No problems, happy coding :-)

Comment: Yes, I have used App Folder Permission and it worked.